# Memory not release in windows store app

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, windows-store-apps, pdf-generation

I have created windows store app using c#. In which i am creating image form pdf using pdfdocument class and display in the image. 
on button click i am removing the objects and call garbage collector 
 after disposing all object why memory is not released?

```
doc = await PdfDocument.LoadFromFileAsync(file);
        if (doc != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < doc.PageCount; i++)
            {
                PdfPage pdf_page = doc.GetPage((uint)i);

                IRandomAccessStream randomStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();

                await pdf_page.RenderToStreamAsync(randomStream);
                MyImage = new WriteableBitmap((int)pdf_page.Size.Width,(int)pdf_page.Size.Height);
                await MyImage.SetSourceAsync(randomStream);
                await randomStream.FlushAsync();
                randomStream.Dispose();
                pdf_page.Dispose();

             Image img1=new Image();
             img1.Source=MyImage;
           imggrid.Items.Add(img1);
            }


        }
     private void btnunload_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      imggrid.Items.Clear();
        doc = null;
        folder = null;
        file = null;
        GC.Collect();
       GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();
    }
```

Comment: This issue still exists 8 years later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find Memory Leak by using any Memroy Profiler App like '*Sci Tech .NET Memory Profiler*', ...

Comment: Then you haven't a memory leak! After calling GC, memory candidate for garbage collection and program memory not released immediately. If you cared that?

Comment: ya but why it so ? is there any way to release it? is there any way to get memory of an app to initial state?

Comment: Releasing Memory is subject of concern for CLR not you! Why you want to manage memory usage?

Comment: ya but when i load images first time the memory usage is upto 100 mb and after disposing objects it will not get to original state so next time when i will load image again it will increase memory thats my problem.

Comment: I think you should read some doc about GC and Memory usage, maybe [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7d49302b-bc50-4657-b903-938cc6afd9e2/memory-leak-garbage-collection-issues-in-c?forum=csharpgeneral) could help.

Comment: ya its helpful but after doing all that memory not come nearer to initial state, after that i observed some windows store app and found that it also not come to initial state of memory.